# How can I stop following a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

Around two years ago I joined the code jam room. I've never seen any users there, but it's not my issue. I just would like to know how to stop receiving notifications about upcoming code jam events. Thank you all.

Comment: Not sure, maybe you need to "leave" the room? Go to the room and press the "leave" button?

Comment: It was the very first thing I did years ago and so there is only option to 'join the room'. Thanks though

Comment: You clicked "leave" *years ago* and haven't been back since? Yet you're still receiving notifications? This doesn't make much sense. That's certainly not how it's supposed to work.

Comment: There is no ["code jam" room on the SO chat server](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=all&sort=active) nor on [Chat.se](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active)

Comment: If I google it, it seems to be an actual Google event, not a Stack Overflow one. Does the email come from a stackoverflow domain?

Comment: There doesn't seem active events related to "code jam" on [Chat.SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=events&sort=active), [Chat.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=events&sort=active&nohide=true), and [Chat.Meta.SE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=events&sort=active&nohide=true). Did the notification appear on SO Inbox Notification or Chat Room ticker, or was it an email? Can you take a screenshot when it happens again?